# how to send values from javascript to server side(asp.net)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side, server-side

What is the best way to send values from JavaScript (client-side) to the server (asp.net) without refreshing the page?

I want to insert the data into a database but I don't want to refresh the page or change any data on it.

Comment: Try to goole for `asp.net ajax tutorial`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ypu have to use **Ajax** techniques, [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [Asp.net](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/), [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/), and the rest of api and libraries that let you use Ajax techniques.

The easiest one in Asp.net is using builtin Asp.net Ajax functionalities by adding a  **ScriptManager** and **UpdatePanel** to your page

Answer (score 8):

Simple way :

1- Import jquery into your page 
2- create ur function in the cs file of the page like this

```
     [WebMethod]
    public static string Save(string param1,string param2)
    {
        string result;
        //your code must return somthing string
        return result;
    }
```

3- in your aspx page create your function

```
function save(){
var param1 = 'value 1 you need to send to the server should be string';
var param2 = 'value 2 you need to send to the server should be string';
         $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "pagename.aspx/Save",
                  data: "{param1: '"+ param1 +"' , param2 :'"+ param2 +"'}",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  async: false,
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(result){
                 //Successfully gone to the server and returned with the string result of the server side function do what you want with the result  

                  }
                  ,error(er)
                  {
                  //Faild to go to the server alert(er.responseText)
                  }
          });
        }
```

4- Call this function on the button click

for more questions or descriptions of my code and script i'm here  :)

Comment: Are you sure the data line is correct here? I can't understand the logic in your use of " and ' signs. Shouldn't it be something like: `data: "'{param1: '+ param1 +' , param2 :'+ param2 +'}'"`. We just want to concatenate a couple of strings and put " " around the final result.

Comment: well i use this sign " as a container of the stringfyed JSON Object its up to you when you  put the values if the value is a String Type you should deal with it as string so we put the ' sign

Comment: so the resulting data string will look like: {param1: 'blah', param2: 'blahblah'}?

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to use a page method or static methods on a page and use jquery to send or get data from the server side code. This link has a good walkthrough

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 1):

The technique is called [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and there are no shortage of [tutorials](http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/ajax-tutorial.html) and [libraries](http://microjs.com/#ajax) (not to mention support in the big libraries such as [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).

Answer (score 1):

No one actually answered this question. As, "Import jquery" "use ajax" etc. all negate the fact that the OP asked for a javascript solution. This is a one-liner in javascript / very easy to do.

In your javascript you just call the method:

```
PageMethods.SomeMethod('test');
```

Your "SomeMethod" would be a code behind method like this:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string SomeMethod(string param1)
    {
        string result = "The test worked!";
        return result;
    }
```

Rules:
You have to identify your code behind method with a WebMethod attribute. It has to be static. And you have to register a script manager in your page as follows:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="MyScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

Since I am working with an aspx webforms page to do some really simple javascript functions like retrieving / stashing geo location, I put it inside the Form element as required.