# Send QR result to codebehind method with function

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm using as reference this code https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/jquery-html5-qr-code-scanner-using-instascan-js-exampleexample.html when i get the result of the QR y send it to a variable, what I try to do and I don't get a result is that when I want to send a function in the codebehing I never get a response result.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/instascan.min.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <video id="preview" class="col-lg-12"></video>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview') });
                    scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
                        var test = content.toString(); //here i get the variable
                        alert(test);
                        <%=SendToDB(content)%>;
                    });
                    Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
                        if (cameras.length > 0) {
                            scanner.start(cameras[0]);
                        } else {
                            console.error('There is no camera');
                        }
                    }).catch(function (e) {
                        console.error(e);
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Now in codebehind I have something like this

```
public void SendToDB(string content)
{
   string variable = content;
   //here I send it to the database
}
```

Comment: SendToBd, being a server side method,  is not compiled in client script. You'll need to understand how postbacks work (if you're using WebForms) or MVC in order to send/receive data from client to server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to send values from javascript to server side(asp.net)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701880/how-to-send-values-from-javascript-to-server-sideasp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an older question but I was struggling with this too so I wanted to post an answer for anyone else. Try changing your html code to this:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview') });
                scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
                    var test = content.toString(); //here i get the variable
                    alert(test);
                    var options = {};
                    options.url = "Default.aspx/SendToDB";
                    options.type = "POST";
                    options.data = JSON.stringify({ content });
                    options.dataType = "json";
                    options.contentType = "application/json";
                    options.success = function (result) { };
                    options.error = function (err) { };

                    $.ajax(options);
                });
                Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
                    if (cameras.length > 0) {
                        scanner.start(cameras[0]);
                    } else {
                        console.error('There is no camera');
                    }
                }).catch(function (e) {
                    console.error(e);
                });
            </script>
```

What is important here is the "options.url = "Default.aspx/SendToDB";". If the name of your page isn't Default.aspx then you need to change it to the correct page name.

Now in your C# code you need to add [WebMethod] above your function:

```
[WebMethod]
public void SendToDB(string content)
{
   string variable = content;
   //here I send it to the database
}
```